# Export CSV with Ajax-Post from View - ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, csv, post

I'm trying to download a CSV file with my view. I debugged the controller method and it worked and I can see the result, but the download does not start.
[Network>Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL4hq.png)

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileContentResult ReportExecution(int reportId, string parameters)
    {
        var paramDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(parameters);

        var data = this._reportsRepository
            .ExecuteReport
            (
                reportId,
                paramDictionary
            );

        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CsVExport.csv");

        return this.File(data, "text/csv", "CsVExport.csv");
    }
```

MyView:

```
...
</form>
<button onclick="submitForm()">Check Form</button>

<script>

    function submitForm() {
        var form = $('#form');

        var obj = {};
        var elements = $("input, select, textarea", form);

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var name = element.name;
            var value = element.value;

            if (name) {
                obj[name] = value;
            }
        }

        console.log(obj);
        $.post("ReportExecution", { reportId: @ViewBag.ReportId, parameters: JSON.stringify(obj) });

    }

</script>
```

Don't ask why it has this strange procedure to submit. The normal sending of MVC5 doesn't work because my form is very dynamic and I can't pass a model to the controller because it changes all the time.

Comment: You're trying to download file through AJAX, which is not supported. You should create another controller and download file from there and/or use normal submit.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know is AJAX POST is not intended to perform file download action. You can create a controller with GET method to download the file generated from `ExecuteReport`:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileContentResult Download(string fileName)
{
    var data = TempData["CSVFile"] as ...; // specify the type returned by ExecuteReport here

    if (data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        fileName = fileName + ".csv";

        return File(data, "text/csv", fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        // something went wrong
        return new EmptyResult();
    }        
}
```

Then in your AJAX call include `success` function to redirect into controller provided above using file name as parameter and use `TempData`/`Session` variable to pass file content:

**AJAX POST**

```
function submitForm() {
    var form = $('#form');

    var obj = {};

    // create object to pass into action parameter

    console.log(obj);
    $.post("ReportExecution", { reportId: @ViewBag.ReportId, parameters: JSON.stringify(obj) }, function (result) {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Download", "ControllerName")' + '?fileName=' + result;
    });
}
```

**POST action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReportExecution(int reportId, string parameters)
{
    var paramDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(parameters);

    var data = this._reportsRepository
        .ExecuteReport
        (
            reportId,
            paramDictionary
        );

    // pass file content to TempData or Session variable
    TempData["CSVFile"] = data;

    string fileName = "CsVExport";

    // pass file name to redirect into download action
    return Json(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do it this way and then get back to you